# addView to TableRow programatically in for loop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-tablelayout

I'am stuck for about 2 hour in order to try to create a TableRow who was multiples infalted layouts in it.My code looks like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
TableLayout tblLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tblL,parent,false);
TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tblListItems.findViewById(R.id.tableRow );
View headerCell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_col,tblListItems,false);
TextView tvCellName = (TextView) headerCell.findViewById(R.id.tvCellName);

    for(String item: items) {

        tvCellName.setText(item);

        tableRow.addView(tvCellName);
    }

relativeLayout2.addView(tblLayout);
```

The error I get :

`The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

What I'am doing wrong and how should I do it right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view can only have one parent. You're trying to add the same view over and over again.

```
for(String item: items) {

    tvCellName.setText(item);

    tableRow.addView(tvCellName); // this will add the same view.
}
```

If you want to add another view you need to create the view dynamically, inside the `for`, and not inflate it, like:

```
tvCellName = new TextView(this);//this creates a new view, that doesn't have a parent.
```

**edit**

Inflate your views inside the for:

```
 View headerCell;
 TextView tvCellName;
 for(String item: items) {
        headerCell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_col,tblListItems,false);
        tvCellName = (TextView) headerCell.findViewById(R.id.tvCellName);
        tvCellName.setText(item);
        tableRow.addView(tvCellName);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that my TextView need to be from a layout that was inflated. `TextView tvCellName = (TextView) headerCell.findViewById(R.id.tvCellName);`

Comment: You need to create the view dynamically. Your problem is not that. Your problem is that a view **CAN'T** be added multiple times.

Comment: Sorry. The thing is that I don't need to add `tvCellName` to `tableRow`. I need to add `headerCell` which has a `TextView` in it on the table row.